# Error instantiating an embed object in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My goal was to create a Discord.RichEmbed object. Here is the code I tried:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const helpEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
```

And here's the error I got:

```
TypeError: Discord.RichEmbed is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> ([Path to my module])
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:824:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

I am using Node v12.1.0 and Discord.js v^12.0.0-dev

Answer (score 0):

To create a richembed object you need to get if from discordjs itself.

```
const { RichEmbed , Discord} = require("discord.js");
```